# Open XML generates only <NewDataSet /> tag from a full Excel file, but work for other files

Tags: asp.net, xml, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have an excel file full of data, and I'm trying to use **Open XML SDK** to convert this file into xml file.

I followed the documentation and other questions here on stackoverflow. However, the output of the xml file is always `<NewDataSet />`. Knowing that I tried other excel files and it worked fine.

Here is how my excel file looks like:
[image]

And here is my code "I tried two approaches":

The first approach is to use `DataSet.GetXML()`, it returned the same value as the next code does.

```
var xmlDS = new ConvertExcelToXml().GetXML(filePath);
string xmlPath = server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/XML/");

StreamWriter xmlFile = new StreamWriter(xmlPath + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + ".xml");
xmlDS.WriteXml(xmlFile);



//The used method to return the excel file dataset
public DataSet GetXML(string filename)
{
  using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
  {
    ds.Tables.Add(this.ReadExcelFile(filename));
    return ds;
  }
}

//This method used to return DataTable for previous method
private DataTable ReadExcelFile(string filename)
{
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, false))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
                IEnumerable<Sheet> sheetcollection = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();

                string relationshipId = sheetcollection.First().Id.Value;

                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);

                SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
                IEnumerable<Row> rowcollection = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();

                if (rowcollection.Count() == 0)
                {
                    return dt;
                }

                foreach (Cell cell in rowcollection.ElementAt(0))
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(GetValueOfCell(spreadsheetDocument, cell));
                }

                foreach (Row row in rowcollection)
                {
                    DataRow temprow = dt.NewRow();
                    int columnIndex = 0;
                    foreach (Cell cell in row.Descendants<Cell>())
                    {
                        int cellColumnIndex = GetColumnIndex(GetColumnName(cell.CellReference));
                        if (columnIndex < cellColumnIndex)
                        {
                            do
                            {
                                temprow[columnIndex] = string.Empty;
                                columnIndex++;
                            }

                            while (columnIndex < cellColumnIndex);
                        }

                        temprow[columnIndex] = GetValueOfCell(spreadsheetDocument, cell);
                        columnIndex++;
                    }

                    dt.Rows.Add(temprow);
                }
            }
            dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            throw new IOException(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `ReadExcelFile()` works correctly? Does it work for other files and only fails on 1 specific file? And have you checked the contents of the returned `DataTable` while debugging?

Comment: Yes, it has all the 8 columns. I checked while debugging

Comment: @bassfader I double checked, and I noticed that the datatable result doesn't match the excel file data

Comment: Does it work for other files and only fails on 1 specific file? And if it fails only on 1 specific file, have you checked the file to see if it actually is a valid `xlsx` file?

Comment: @bassfader, yes actually it worked with other files. I added more details to the question thanks to your comment. It's like I need to normalize the excel file or something before getting datatable from it.